# uploading po file with new strings to transifex?

Tags: localization, transifex

I use an open-sourced library which uses transifex as translation-collaboration tool.

The language I'm interested in is not fully translated yet, and I'm trying to translate the left-overs. 
Besides, I added few new strings to the project, and need to translate those as well.

If I hadn't added new strings, I could have just translated what's missing and submit it to transfix and be done.

How should I handle the new strings I added when committing my translations to transfix?

Is it possible to commit `hunks` to transifex as possible in git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you add new strings to your project you should upload your updated PO file to Transifex too. This will allow you to translate your new strings into your languages.

*Note*: you should upload the whole .po file to transifex, and not just the new strings, because otherwise the old strings will be considered outdated and will be deleted.

I'm not sure which library you are using to integrate your project with Transifex, so I'll just list the most common ways to upload your PO file to Transifex.

- Using the web interface. You can go to the options page for your resource and upload your new PO file. [resource options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5tcd.png)
- Using the command line client. You can use the client to push your new source file. You will be interested in running `tx push -s`, assuming you have configured your settings properly. (I'm saying properly because by default the `source_file` option is not populated, and you need it in order to use the `-s` flag)
- Using the [API](http://support.transifex.com/customer/portal/articles/1009524-resource-api#source-methods). You can issue a PUT request like `curl -i -L --user user:password -F file=@en/django.po -X PUT https://www.transifex.com/api/2/project/transifex/resource/core/content/`